# Finding a line L perpendicular to line T that passes through point P in R3?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

The question asks:
Find the line through $(3,1,-2)$ that intersects and is perpendicular to

$$x = -1 + t, y = -2 + t, z = -1 + t.$$

My thoughts:
Say the point of intersection is $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$, then my line can be of the form

$$L(s) = (3,1,-2) + (x_0- 3,y_0- 1,z_0+ 2)s$$

Then I tried setting up a system of equations at the intersection like this:

$$-1 + t = 3 + (x_0- 3)s$$

$$-2 + t = 1 + (y_0- 1)s$$

$$-1 + t = -2 + (z_0+ 2)s$$

And tried finding the point $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$, but I feel that I'm not on the right track. Could someone explain to me how to appropriately tackle this problem?

Comment: Your thoughts are the correct ones; solving this will give you the correct solution, but you need to put in the conditions for orthogonality to obtain the unique solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an approach. Find a normal vector to the directional vector $(-1,-2,-1)$ of the given line, then use it (together with finding a point on the line $L$) to find the equation of the perpendicular line.

Comment: Isn't the directional vector (1,1,1)? Looking at the coefficients of t?

Answer (score 0):

These kind of problems are especially appropriate to Grassmann algebra so, if I may, I would like to show this approach using the Mathematica code of John Browne. First, some nomenclature:

[image]

Load the package, define a 3-dimensional space with an origin, define t as a scalar.

```
<< GrassmannCalculus`
SetPreferences["Grassmann3Space", "Vector"]
DeclareExtraScalarSymbols[t]
```

We will use the idea that when the vector from the fixed point to the line is a minimum length, the vector must be perpendicular to the line.

Define the fixed point, a parameterized line, and a parameterized vector from the fixed point to a point on the line.

[image]

Giving for the point on the line and the vector from the fixed point to the line point:

[image]

We calculate the length squared of the vector from the point to the line as a function of t and minimize by solving for when the derivative is zero.

[image]

Giving:

[image]

The resulting vector from the fixed point to the line is:

[image]

If the answer is correct, the scalar product of the vector12 and the direction of the line should be zero.

[image]